# What kind of mongodb data type is this?

Tags: mongodb

At: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar/real-time-analytics-with-mongodb slide 
"**Pre-Aggregation**". What are:

```
metadata: {
  date: '...'
  site: '...'
}
hourly: { 
  "0": 2312, 
  "1": 271235
  ...
}
```

Are these arrays inside a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a sample document from a collection, with arrays or hashes stored in attributes. There's a great O'Reilly book that describes this technique (basically, nesting like that helps speed up searching within the document.):

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019893.do

Look for "Tip 26: Create hierarchical documents for faster scans"